# multiple file upload and handler

Tags: javascript, php

I have a website with file upload capability. Now i would like to make it to multiple file upload.

Here is the main file:

```
<form action="update.php?KBID=<?=$KBID ?>&offset=<?=$offset ?>&Action=Update&tabName=<?=$secondtabs_param; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form2" id="form2" onSubmit="handleUploadedZipFile($KBID, $file, $zipfilename)" >
Attachments:<input type="file" id="zipfile" name="zipfile" multiple> 
</form>
```

the onclick function is:

```
function handleUploadedZipFile($KBID, $file, $zipfilename){    
if (!empty($_FILES['zipfile'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['zipfile']['name'] as $key => $temp) {
        $name = $_FILES['zipfile']['name'][$key];
        $type = $_FILES['zipfile']['type'][$key];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['zipfile']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $error = $_FILES['zipfile']['error'][$key];
        $size = $_FILES['zipfile']['size'][$key];

        $zipfilename = $name;

        if ($size > 0) {
            $dir = PROBLEMZIPS."/".sprintf("%05d",$KBID)."/";
            $result = getUploadedFile($tmp_name,$dir,$zipfilename);
        } else {
            $result = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You've not said what your problem is; what do you expect to happen with the script and what actually happens?

Comment: i wanna allow my users to upload multiple files thatz the basic thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is not full working code but get a clear idea how you could achieve your requirement.
 You need slightly modified your **handleUploadedZipFile** function and add uploaded functionality like this:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['zipfile'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['zipfile']['name'] as $key => $temp) {
        $name = $_FILES['zipfile']['name'][$key];
        $type = $_FILES['zipfile']['type'][$key];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['zipfile']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $error = $_FILES['zipfile']['error'][$key];
        $size = $_FILES['zipfile']['size'][$key];

        $zipfilename = $name;

        if ($size > 0) {
            $dir = PROBLEMZIPS."/".sprintf("%05d",$KBID)."/";
            $result = getUploadedFile($tmp_name,$dir,$zipfilename);
        } else {
            $result = false;
        }
    }
}
```

and make file field as array by replace zipfile with **zipfile[]**, i.e:

```
<input type="file" id="zipfile" name="zipfile[]" multiple>
```

Comment: can u also help me with the other two handlers? the other two scripts also?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean other two handler. do you mean getPostPutField and getUploadedFile?

Comment: was mentioning these two functions:                             function escFileValues(){}
if(getPostPutField('zipfilename',$zipfilename)){}                          in the above question

Comment: Sorry I can't help about those two handler because I don't know whats doing in those two.

Comment: it is basically just useless functions calling each other

Comment: Amin i have now changed my code as per your answer and it seems only file was uploaded and not others. can u help me on this?

Comment: Here is I prepare a simple multiple upload file example for you http://pastebin.com/f12wGDBi